# i want to display another screen to ask for OTP in Credential Provider

Tags: credential-providers

I am developing a 2-factor authentication credential provider. I want to stop windows from logging in after user enter username and password. I want it to give me  Edit_Text_Field in the next screen/tile. how can I achieve this?
can anyone specifically point to the functions in the credential provider to do this? i am using SampleAllControlsCredentialProvider.

Comment: Have a look at `SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider`.

I think it can feet your requirements. 

There are extra combo box appended to existing `CLSID_PasswordCredentialProvider`

Answer (score 1):

You can implement technique with hiding and revealing some of controls. I'm doing the same way in my own Credential Provider:

Before your code return control from `GetSerialization` method it can hide username/password fields `SetFieldState(..., CPFS_HIDDEN);` and reveal OTP field.

Don't forget to set output parameter `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE *pcpgsr` to `CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED` value.

On the next turn your provider can be supplied with OTP value and finally return `CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED`.